# Preventing browser to scroll back to TOP of the page after loading it [LINK FIXED]

Tags: anchor, loading, external, html

## The Problem

When you click a external link with a anchor:

1. You will be redirected to that page
2. You will go imediately to the anchor in the link
3. Page will finish loading (you'll be at the anchor already)
4. Page finishes loading - Goes back to TOP of the page

Live example... External URL linking straight to an anchor: [www.mysite.com/index.html#sources_and_credits](http://docs.revaxarts.com/doc_fe95e477c134e16d95f20a873d3680a6/#sources_and_credits)

I have added some heavy images to this example just so it takes a little bit to load and reproduce a document with lots of content and smaller images. Please refresh page and consider clearing cache if it didn't bug with you at first try.

How to solve?

Comment: Live example link Fixed. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the documenter and you link isn't valid anymore because I delete created documentations after one hour.

So I'll explain it with a working example:

http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/docs/

If you would like to deeplink you can use this: http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/docs/#autosave which brings you directly to that page (native browser behavior). Although the script tries to scroll to the point as well and starts at the top.

To prevent this native behavior you can use this link http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/docs/#!/autosave which let you start at the top and if the DOM is ready it scrolls to that anchor.

Of course this is something custom made and not a native behavior.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It bugs in the first visit (not in cache) Try by yourself: http://revaxarts-themes.com/documenter/docs/#!/what_else (clear cache first)

Comment: Google Chrome latest version, Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 64 bits

Comment: Try making a temporary documenter with some heavy images on it, and then click a direct anchor to the bottom of the document. The behavior of the browser when you do that wil be: Will open the document, go to anchor while loading content, finish loading content, goes back to top... It shouldn't go back to top, because then the anchor loses it's purpose